# Flutter double to Time in hours

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert a double value (e.g. 9.5) to a corresponding hour/minute value (e.g. 9.30). I also want to perform calculations using this value, but handle it like a time value (e.g. adding 23 and 2 should result in 1 as the hours should wrap around at 24 hours).

I already tried to convert the value to DateTime, but it says "invalid date format".

Comment: What do you mean by 25 should go to 1?

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: There is no built-in way to convert a `double` to a `DateTime` in the way you describe.  You'll need to implement such a conversion manually in the same way you'd do it if you were to do it by hand (e.g. separate integer and fractional parts, mod the integer part by 24, and use the fractional part to compute the number of minutes).

Comment: @AjilO. Like at 24 hours it should go to one, just like a clock. So I can do actual math with it, e.g. 22 o'clock + 8 hours.

Comment: @amugofjava See me reply to AjilO.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it

```dart
void main() {
  print(getTimeStringFromDouble(9.5)); // 9:30
  print(getTimeStringFromDouble(25.0)); // 1:0
}

String getTimeStringFromDouble(double value) {
  if (value < 0) return 'Invalid Value';
  int flooredValue = value.floor();
  double decimalValue = value - flooredValue;
  String hourValue = getHourString(flooredValue);
  String minuteString = getMinuteString(decimalValue);

  return '$hourValue:$minuteString';
}

String getMinuteString(double decimalValue) {
  return '${(decimalValue * 60).toInt()}'.padLeft(2, '0');
}

String getHourString(int flooredValue) {
  return '${flooredValue % 24}'.padLeft(2, '0');
}
```

Comment: 1. You probably should assert `value >= 0` to exclude negative numbers, 2. `getMinuteString()` should do `padLeft(2, '0')`.

Comment: @jamesdlinYep. Thanks